# Opencv reboots windows

Tags: opencv, python

Opencv keeps crashing my computer. It seems like it only happens when it is computing very hard. It happens at random times and does not give a blue screen. Just reboots.
Code works completely fine on my i7.

Python 3.9.4
openCV 4.5.3
win 10
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X

Anyone else experienced this or have some insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some issue with AMD core management. Just running the code on a specific core solved my issue.

On windows, you do that by:
start /affinity X mysript.py
X is the dec of the core combo. 1 will run on core 1, 2 will run on core 2, 3 will run on core 1+2, and so on.